# Story Identification - post-apocalyptic novel solar incident, new time and old time

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I'm trying to identify and find a story set in a post-apocalyptic world (probably based in USA/California but not 100%) where something has happened to the Sun, and as a result probably changed human genetics somehow and some people live on 'Old Time' and others live on 'New Time'.

The book sounded interesting during a radio review but I can't remember the title or author.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whew! That's not much to go by. You sure you can't provide some more information?

Comment: I think it was a written by female author - that's literally all I can remeber

Comment: I think additionally, wherever the story is based, there was perpetual sunlight and there were 2 distinct tribes of 'survivors'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I literally spent the entire day trying different combinations of words on Google and I've at last found what I was looking for!   It's: **The Age of Miracles by Karen Thomson Walker**